# When using 'SearchFilter' I get an error when trying to search

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When I use the search function in my api I get an error that says "Cannot resolve keyword 'q/c' into field.  Choices are: 'XXX'" The q or c depends on which api page I am on. The 'c' I presume stands for my choices one and the 'q' I presume stands for the Questions one.

```
from rest_framework import generics  
from . serializers import QuestionSerializer, ChoiceSerializer  
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend  
from rest_framework.filters import OrderingFilter, SearchFilter


from polls.models import Choice, Question


# need to create a view for each serializer class QuestionList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer  # set the serializer
    queryset = Question.objects.all()  # set the query set to all the objects of that view
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter, SearchFilter)  # allows for filters
    filter_fields = {'id': ['gte', 'lte', 'exact'], 'pub_date': ['gte', 'lte']}
    ordering_fields = ('id', 'question_text', 'pub_date')
    search_fields = 'question_text'


class ChoiceList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ChoiceSerializer
    queryset = Choice.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter, SearchFilter)
    # trying to do greater than or less than filter fields stuff
    filter_fields = {'id': ['gte', 'lte', 'exact'], 'votes': ['gte', 'lte', 'exact']}
    ordering_fields = ('id', 'votes', 'choice_text', 'question',)
    search_fields = 'choice_text'
```

[Here's the error page I get when i try to use search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGgEI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter) says the following:

> The `search_fields` attribute should be a **list of names** of text type fields on the model

You are assigning a strings to both `search_fields` variables. Change this to either a list or tuple as follows:

```
search_fields = ('question_text',)
search_fields = ('choice_text',)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am an idiot lol. I appreciate your help!